# Trace back the original URL from the CDN link

Tags: cdn

Not sure if it is an appropriate question to ask. If it doesn't, I can delete the question.

Basically, I would like to see if it is possible to trace back the actual URL link from the CDN link?

For example, I download a pic from a CDN link with my application and I would like to trace back the original URL. Is it possible to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You assume that a pull zone is used. It depends on the CDN setup. There are chances where you'll see the origin URL. Sometimes it's explicitly declared as an extra HTTP header in order to improve SEO. Here's how: Take a closer look on the HTTP headers of this particular file. Sometimes you'll find the HTTP header "link" (rel="canonical").

An origin URL is not a must for a CDN. It's also possible that the content has been directly uploaded to the CDN ("push zone").